# How to retrieve records from the database where at least 3 of 10 column values are present?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to retrieve records from the database where *at least* 3 of 10 column values are present. That is, if I have a class (a MySQL database table) with 10 attributes (table columns) whose values can be `nil` (`null`), then I would like to perform a query so to return objects (records) where at least 3 of those 10 attribute values are present (not `null`).

Is it possible? If so, how to make that?

**UPDATE** If I have a class (a MySQL database table) with 10 attributes (table columns) whose values can be `nil` (`null`) *or* "" (*not* `null`), then I would like to perform a query so to return objects (records) where at least 3 of those 10 attribute values are present (not `null` *and* not "").

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - The answer to the question is intended to help to build that.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - I'm no very expert on MySQL... maybe it is possible to make that with some "internal" Ruby on Rails method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could compare against the sum of testing each individual column [`IS NOT NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-not-null) [`AND`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) [`<>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal):

```sql
WHERE (  (colA IS NOT NULL AND colA <> ' ')
       + (colB IS NOT NULL AND colB <> ' ')
       + ...
       + (colJ IS NOT NULL AND colJ <> ' ')
      ) >= 3
```

This works because the boolean result of each test is implicitly converted to either `1` (if true) or `0` (if false); therefore the sum is the number of columns which are neither `NULL` nor `' '`.

Alternatively, you could handle the `NULL` case using [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull):

```sql
WHERE (IFNULL(colA<>' ',0) + IFNULL(colB<>' ',0) + ... + IFNULL(colJ<>' ',0)) >= 3
```

Comment: I hope that all the answers are just like yours... thank you.